# Get MySQL Server time as part of a Sequelize findOne() query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

As part of a call to `findOne()` (or a custom method) on my Sequelize model I want to get back a field in that model that has the DB's current datetime.

Or, is there a better way to solve this problem: I want to compare the value in the `updatedAt` field with the DB server's current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, DB server's current time is the current time of your server system minus the time zone (hours/minutes) because DB uses the Universal time to store timestamp by default.

But when you fetch that date and try new Date() in server code, it will automatically convert it to the current time zone.

So you can just compare new Date() and new Date(modelData.updatedAt) to find out your answer.

Comment: Assuming that MySQL is running on another machine aren't you then comparing a DateTime created on one server with the DateTime created on another and those system clocks might have times that are different. i.e. one might be faster than the other.